# Can eventRender render today's event only?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the Fullcalendar for a project. What I want to do was just render the event where I clicked on a day. I've implemented the eventRender method but it is called for every event created before the current one.
Is there any work around to render the only event created currently?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or post some of your code?

Comment: I guess you have to change the id propertie for each event.